# How to print orders with the gift card message?

Tags: print, gift-card

When printing an order from Sales - Orders - select an order - then - Actions - Print All - SUBMIT....it prints the order but it does not contain the gift card message. Is there an easy way to include the gift card message in the printing?

Answer (score 0):

please check link bellow.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236263/magento-getting-giftcard-code-and-amount

I hope this will help you.